# disable rtkit-daemon.service service when selinux is disabled

Tags: linux, rhel, security, selinux, system-calls

we have Hadoop cluster , each machine in the cluster is rhel 7.6 version

since the provider - hortonworks recommended to disable the selinux

then we disabled the selinux on all rhel machines

now about `rtkit-daemon.service` , from man page ( https://linux.die.net/man/8/rtkit_daemon_selinux ) I understand that this service is also related to selinuex

so i assume that if selinuex is disable then we can also to stop the service rtkit-daemon.service and disabled it

but I am not sure about this ,

I will appreciate to get advice if we can stop and disable the service - rtkit-daemon.service

```
systemctl status rtkit-daemon.service
● rtkit-daemon.service - RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rtkit-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-12-13 21:55:23 UTC; 10h ago
 Main PID: 6400 (rtkit-daemon)
    Tasks: 3
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/rtkit-daemon.service
           └─6400 /usr/libexec/rtkit-daemon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re looking at the `rtkit_daemon_selinux` documentation, which only covers the SELinux policy for `rtkit-daemon`.

`rtkit`, RealtimeKit, is unrelated to SELinux and shouldn’t be disabled just because you’ve disabled SELinux. See [the RealtimeKit `README`](http://git.0pointer.net/rtkit.git/tree/README) for details.

Comment: regarding to rtkit-daemon.service , why we need this service , or in which case we need it , because we want to disable all service that are not in used

Comment: That’s another question.

Comment: ok so do you think I need to post another question? or update the current question?

Comment: You should ask Hortonworks / Cloudera, or your RHEL contacts; the answer is going to be very specific to your usage scenarios.